# I'm unable to rename a file in linux system using perl

Tags: perl

I'm just a beginner in Perl. I try to rename a file or directory using the following script, but it is not renaming the file. Please help me in identifying the problem.

I'm using Perl version 5.8.4

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Copy;
my $dir="/home/hari/perl-s/abc/";
opendir (DIR, $dir);
my @fileList = readdir DIR;

foreach (@fileList){
    next if -d;
    my $oldname = $_;
    print "Newfile after assigning: $_ \n";
    s/(^[0-9])(.)//;
    print "Newfile: $_ \n";
    print "oldname: $oldname \n";
    rename ($oldname,$_);
}
```

Comment: `use autodie` or check the return value of `opendir` and `rename`, e.g. `opendir ... or die "Couldn't open dir: $!";`

Comment: Please show some sample input and what you expect the output to be.

Comment: Are you trying to strip away the first two characters of file names that start with a number?

Comment: possible duplicate of [No such file or directory error: Perl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24334829/no-such-file-or-directory-error-perl)

Comment: Yes that's right im stripping away first two numeric characters with an empty value

Comment: say for in my directory i have 01file, 02file2,03file3,4file4 and i have to rename it file1,file2,file3,file4. like this

Answer (score 2):

The return values of `readdir` are just filenames; they do not include the path that was provided to `opendir`. You generally have to include that manually.

```
opendir (DIR, $dir);
my @fileList = readdir DIR;

foreach (@fileList){
    # $_ is just "filename"
    $_ = "$dir/$_";   # now $_ is "/home/hari/perl-s/abc/$filename"
    next if -d;
    ...
}
```

There's more than one way to do things in Perl. Another way to get the set of files in a directory is with the `glob` function. One of the advantages of `glob` is that you can use it in such a way so that it returns filenames with their full paths, and so sometimes `glob` is preferable to the `opendir/readdir/closedir` idioms:

```
my @filelist = glob("$dir/*");
foreach (@filelist) {
    # $_ is "/home/hari/perl-s/abc/filename"
    ...
}
```